# Getting float numbers out of a list with both strings and floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

This is the first time I'm asking a question and I'm not an expert in programming, so be nice to me. :)

I am currently using an external code in phyton that permanently provides me with the current bitcoin price. Unfortunately, this function not only provides the price, but also fills the list with the selected currency, for example. but i just want a list with numerical values.

Here is the formatting of the list for an entry:

```
[{'BTC': {'EUR': 28843.76}}]
```

Hope anyone can help me!

Comment: Is it always in this exact format? and the currency is fixed?

Comment: Have you made _any_ attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The output is in the form of a dictionary in a list. So what you can do is get the value ('EUR':28843.76) from the key ('BTC').

We can do that using the get() function:

```
input = [{'BTC': {'EUR': 28843.76}}] #Initializing the list.
for i in input: # Just going to iterate through the list
    firstset = i.get('BTC') # Gives firstset the value of {'EUR':28843.76}
```

Now we have the above value. As it is another dictionary, we can use get() again:

```
value = firstset.get('EUR')
```

Now value contains the numerical i.e. 28843.76

Read this to learn about dictionaries - [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked fine! Would tip you some Dogecoin if i had any.

Comment: @MaximilianMielke You can accept the answer (green tick mark) if it does what you need